# CoCreateInstance returns EFAIL inside the static function

Tags: c++, winapi, static-methods

I am developing a visual c++ application for creating preview handler. 
The problem occurs when i for some reason i need to do CoCreateInstance() for IXMLDOMDocument *pDomDoc; inside the **static function** (pay attention here).
and the syntax is as follows-

```
//this CreateHtmlPreview is declared static somewhere in my code
HRESULT AMEPreviewHandler:: CreateHtmlPreview(AMEPreviewHandler* instance)
{
    IStream *m_FinalHTMLStream;
    ULONG pcbWritten;
    HRESULT hrs = CreateStreamOnHGlobal(NULL, TRUE, &m_FinalHTMLStream);
    HRESULT hrp = m_FinalHTMLStream->Write(&(instance->m_HtmlFileContents),(instance->m_SizeOfFile)-1, &pcbWritten);
IXMLDOMDocument *pDomDoc;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(DOMDocument60), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pDomDoc));
//the problem is here that this hr on debugging gives EFAIL

         if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
     ................Something..something.......
}
}
```

Is that due to static declaration of the function.If NO ?? Then what could be the reason for this EFAIL ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `CoCreateInstance` has no knowledge of whether or not it is made from a `static` function or not. The fact that you are calling from a `static` function is not the problem. It is perfectly fine to call `CoCreateInstance` from any type of function.

Comment: So do you have what could be the reason for the hr=EFAIL on debugging ??

Comment: Could be practically anything. I just answered the question that you asked.

Comment: and another important thing if i try to know the error type by doing this MessageBoxA((instance->m_hwndPreview),strerror(hr),"BTN WND", MB_ICONINFORMATION); then it gives **UnKnown Error**